# The connection to the server 192.168.1.11:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, flannel

I have configured a 2 ubuntu VM in Virtual box where configured k8s, i am unable to get out of "kubectl get node" output.

I have configured one master and one slave, "u-worker1" is not ready beacause i shutdown that machine..

The main problem is sometime it works and sometime it won't, i am not sure what causing here..

```
root@master:~# kubectl get node
NAME        STATUS     ROLES           AGE   VERSION
master      Ready      control-plane   41h   v1.25.4
u-worker1   NotReady   <none>          41h   v1.25.4
root@master:~#
```

```
root@master:~#
root@master:~# kubectl get pod -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS         AGE
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-798cc86c47-rddgx   1/1     Running            10 (2m8s ago)    40h
kube-system   calico-node-4nstx                          0/1     Running            9 (2m27s ago)    40h
kube-system   calico-node-qsvdg                          0/1     Init:0/3           0                40h
kube-system   calico-typha-667b5bfff9-nz552              0/1     Pending            0                40h
kube-system   coredns-565d847f94-2mthg                   1/1     Running            6 (65s ago)      41h
kube-system   coredns-565d847f94-vm46p                   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5 (30s ago)      41h
kube-system   etcd-master                                1/1     Running            37 (6m12s ago)   41h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-master                      1/1     Running            35 (7m43s ago)   41h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-master             0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   42 (11s ago)     41h
kube-system   kube-proxy-98c2f                           0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8 (40h ago)      40h
kube-system   kube-proxy-c98cm                           0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   41 (41s ago)     41h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-master                      1/1     Running            41 (6m3s ago)    41h
root@master:~#
```

```
root@master:~# kubectl get pod
The connection to the server 192.168.1.11:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
root@master:~#
```

I tried reconfiguration, changed almost all CNI & i tried moving config file at other folder still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the pods status it is clear that most of the components are failed with CrashLoopBackOff error.
You need to revisit the steps that are followed to setup the cluster. If you can  share the steps we can review it and confirm what went wrong.
Cheack the pod logs/pod description of kube-controller manager, coredns, kube-proxy pods also might help

Note: Make sure to put the information that you have posted is put in proper format and is easily readable.